# Any solution for multi-tenant setup with different DNS?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, multi-tenant, kubernetes-ingress

I have set up my frontend cluster in my Kubernetes and exposed as `frontend.loaner.com` and I want to point the DNS record of these both `johndoe.loaner.com`, `janedoe.loaner.com` to see the `frontend.loaner.com`.

Is that possible to just point two DNS to a 1 running server and works fine still having the hostname?

I read about the CNAME but it will redirect me to `frontend.loaner.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a Kubernetes [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). Basically, something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: frontend.loaner.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: backend1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: johndoe.loaner.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: backend2
          servicePort: 80
  - host: janedoe.loaner.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: backend3
          servicePort: 80
```

The above Ingress resource assumes you are using an [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) in your cluster.

Comment: clarification, so would I create DNS record pointing all to my frontend.loaner.com?

Comment: For the example above you need 3 records one for each `frontend.loaner.com`, `johndoe.loaner.com`, `janedoe.loaner.com` pointing to the same load balancer fronting your ingress.